# Adding content before specific line number(s) in a text file using Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

So I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
a1
b1
c1 
a2 
b2 
c2
.
.
.
```

Now I want to index each component of this text file such that is looks like this:

```
0:
a1
b1
c1
1:
a2
b2
c2
.
.
.
```

I tried developing several shell scripts but unfortunately couldn't achieve the above-mentioned objective. It would be really great if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to perform the above-mentioned task using shell scripting. Thanks!

**PS: I'm a macOS user ( Just letting you know since awk/sed commands perform a bit differently on macOS & Linux )**

Comment: How can you recognize where a new component starts? Or are the line numbers known?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input
a1
b1
c1
a2
b2
c2
.
.
.
$ awk '/^a/{printf "%d:\n", counter++}1' input
0:
a1
b1
c1
1:
a2
b2
c2
.
.
.
```

Or:

`awk '/^a/{print counter++ ":" }1' input`, but `printf` feels cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner, which relies on the assumption that there are exactly 3 lines per each group that shares the same index:

```
echo 'a1 b1 c1 a2 b2 c2 a3 b3 c3' | xargs -n1 > in_file
perl -lpe '$i = (($. - 1) / 3); print "$i:" if ! (($. - 1) % 3);' in_file > out_file
```

Contents of `out_file`:

```
0:
a1
b1
c1
1:
a2
b2
c2
2:
a3
b3
c3
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`$.` : Current input line number.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{key=$0; gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",key)} key != prev{print (key-1)":"} {print; prev=key}' file
0:
a1
b1
c1
1:
a2
b2
c2
```